# regex to match if not repeated specific times

Tags: javascript, regex

The title probably didn't make much sense, so let me make it clear:

I want to catch space characters that are not repeated one or three times. And replace them with nothing.

For example, this;

```
'the quick brown   fox jumps      over  the   lazy dog'
```

would become this;

```
'the quick brown   fox jumps over the lazy dog'
```

Currently i get by with `split`ing the string by three spaces, then by one space and cleaning empty indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match 2 spaces or 4+ spaces, with word boundaries around them:

```
newstr = str.replace(/\b(\s\s|\s{4,})\b/g, ' ');
```

`\b` matches word boundaries, that will keep `\s\s` from matching the two spaces inside a 3-character sequence.

The `g` modifier makes it replace all the matches in the input string.

Comment: I did make a mistake, I forgot the `g` flag

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace` :

```
var str = 'the quick brown   fox jumps      over  the   lazy dog';
var res = str.replace(/\b\s{2}\b|\b{4,}\b/g, " ");
```

The regex `/ {4,}/i` will match 4 or more space.and `\s{2}` match 2 space.

Comment: @Barmar yep, fixed ;)

Comment: That will delete one of the two spaces that are inside a 3-space sequence

Comment: @Barmar yeah it needs boundary!

Comment: Now just add the `g` modifier instead of `i`.